# HTML5 Canvas - how to get absolute position of an object after rotate?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

Do you have any idea, how to get absolute position of an object after rotate? In Canvas, when we use context.rotate() we actually rotate everything including the x and y axes. So actually positions of each objects are the same. Isn't it right?

I need to know the absolute postion from the left top corner of an objects after any transformations. It must me possible but I don't know how. Too hard for me... please give me some advices or suggestions how to do this.

Big thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For what reason do you need it?  A hack to figure it out could be just loading your canvas and inspecting it.

Otherwise you could create a couple of functions to use the rotation to calculate it.

I'm assuming you're hoping for a built in method or function that will simply give it to you but I do not know of one.